# telnet aspmx.l.google.com and it try ipv6 first

Tags: linux, telnet

well, I try to send email via google 'aspmx.l.google.com' server, port 25.
I can send emial, technically. I just have to wait one minute to wait the sending process complete.

Then I try to do telnet to aspmx.l.google.com from my terminal and I found that it tries ipv6 first and then tries ipv4 after ipv6 is timeout.

I believe that is why I need to wait a minute for sending email.

BTW: I am doing it locally.

Does anyone know what is the real problem and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will probably get better answers on serverfault.com. How does `telnet -4 aspmx.l.google.com` work for you? Do you have defaults set for telnet (eg. `/etc/telnetrc`)?

Comment: Well, I will try there~ thanks

Comment: It works fine~ So I am thinking it must be some default value cause this problem. But I don't in which file I have such setting, or may be it is in my global env.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to comment out or append the following line to /etc/gai.conf file

> precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100

Comment: It works perfect, thanks man. I am just trying to look for something like this. Some setting or config file to set try ipv4 first

Comment: Good one @gino. +1 for teaching me something new on IP resolution.